# Changing view layout_width attribute (even to 0) does not affect actual view width

Tags: android, android-layout, width

I was following an Android tutorial about `RelativeLayout` which just made a basic layout of two `EditTexts` (first name and last name fields) and a `Button`(not important). The first name `EditText` view had a `layout_width` of 0dp, but was still visible on the screen. I messed around with the width value and it seemed that no matter what value I gave it, the size of the `EditText` stayed the same. Why is that? Does it have something to do with the `layout_toLeftOf` statement? Below are links to the tutorial along with a picture of my xml code and the resulting output.

Tutorial Link: http://tinyurl.com/jjnfw7z

[image: note: the button code/output is not a worry]

[image: 2]]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The width of the `EditText` with id `first_name` is completely specified by these two constraints:

```
android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/last_name"
```

- `android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"` implies that the left edge of this `EditText` must match the left edge of the parent view.
- `android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/last_name"` implies that the right edge of this `EditText` must match the left edge of the sibling view with id `last_name`.

By design, these take priority over any specified `layout_width` value, which is why you can change that `dp` width with no visible effect. It is common to set the width to `0dp` in such cases; since the `layout_width` attribute is required, a value of zero is the clearest possible indicator that the view's width is being determined elsewhere (by other attributes; in code, etc.)